# How to debug a macro annotation?

Tags: scala, scala-macros

### Background

I'm trying to add a `@Prisms` annotation to Monocle that will work as follows. Given:

```
@Prisms sealed trait Foo
case object A extends Foo
case object B extends Foo
```

it will generate a companion object for `Foo`:

```
object Foo {
  val a = monocle.macros.GenPrism.apply[Foo, A]
  val b = monocle.macros.GenPrism.apply[Foo, B]
}
```

(or if the companion object already exists, it will add those methods to it).

The macro relies on `directKnownSubclasses` to find `A` and `B`, so there will be a note in the Monocle readme recommending that people use Typelevel Scala. I've configured Monocle to use TLS on my branch.

### First attempt

I tried using `TypeName`s to represent the parent type `Foo` and child type (`A` or `B`):

```
def findSubclasses(typeName: TypeName): Set[TypeName] = {
  // Note: disable macros to prevent stack overflow caused by infinite typing loop!
  val tpe = c.typecheck(Ident(typeName), mode = c.TYPEmode, silent = true, withMacrosDisabled = true)
  tpe.symbol.asClass.knownDirectSubclasses.map(_.asType.name)
}

def prisms(parentTypename: TypeName, childNames: Set[TypeName]): Set[Tree] = childNames.map { childName =>
  val prismName = TermName(prefix + childName.decodedName.toString.toLowerCase)
  q"""val $prismName = monocle.macros.GenPrism.apply[$parentTypename, $childName]"""
}
```

This generates what looks like reasonable code:

```
{
  sealed trait Foo;
  object Foo {
    val a = monocle.macros.GenPrism.apply[Foo, A];
    val b = monocle.macros.GenPrism.apply[Foo, B]
  };
  ()
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work:

```
[error] /Users/chris/code/Monocle/test/shared/src/test/scala/other/PrismsAnnotationSpec.scala:5: not found: type A
[error] @monocle.macros.Prisms sealed trait Foo
[error]  ^
[error] one error found
```

### Second attempt

I also tried using `TypeSymbol`s instead of `TypeName`s:

```
def prisms(parentTypename: TypeName, childSymbols: Set[TypeSymbol]): Set[Tree] = {
  val parentSymbol: TypeSymbol = 
    c.typecheck(Ident(parentTypename), mode = c.TYPEmode, silent = true, withMacrosDisabled = true)
      .symbol
      .asType
  childSymbols.map { childSymbol =>
    val prismName = TermName(prefix + childSymbol.name.decodedName.toString.toLowerCase)
    q"""val $prismName = monocle.macros.GenPrism.apply[$parentSymbol, $childSymbol]"""
  }
}
```

But this gives me the following error, so I'm guessing the generated tree is invalid:

```
[error] /Users/chris/code/Monocle/test/shared/src/test/scala/other/PrismsAnnotationSpec.scala:5: macro annotation could not be expanded (the most common reason for that is that you need to enable the macro paradise plugin; another possibility is that you try to use macro annotation in the same compilation run that defines it)
[error] @monocle.macros.Prisms sealed trait Foo
[error]  ^
[error] one error found
```

### Third attempt

I also tried turning the `TypeSymbol`s into `Type`s:

```
def prisms(parentTypename: TypeName, childSymbols: Set[TypeSymbol]): Set[Tree] = {
  val parentSymbol: TypeSymbol = 
    c.typecheck(Ident(parentTypename), mode = c.TYPEmode, silent = true, withMacrosDisabled = true)
      .symbol
      .asType
  childSymbols.map { childSymbol =>
    val prismName = TermName(prefix + childSymbol.name.decodedName.toString.toLowerCase)
    q"""val $prismName = monocle.macros.GenPrism.apply[${parentSymbol.toType}, ${childSymbol.toType}]"""
  }
}
```

But I get the same error, saying the annotation could not be expanded.

Now I'm out of ideas.

### How to reproduce

The complete code is available on this branch: https://github.com/cb372/Monocle/tree/sealed-trait-macro-annotation.

- [First attempt](https://github.com/cb372/Monocle/blob/c0185125665d2378275985ba83978f7fa8843cc1/macro/shared/src/main/scala/monocle/macros/Prisms.scala)
- [Second attempt](https://github.com/cb372/Monocle/blob/efd54537f10bd1e0ed7a9764121e8e900de123f1/macro/shared/src/main/scala/monocle/macros/Prisms.scala)
- [Third attempt](https://github.com/cb372/Monocle/blob/3290ca6e01c57c08ec0ad0fc755efbf774551cb7/macro/shared/src/main/scala/monocle/macros/Prisms.scala)

The macro is used in `test/shared/src/test/scala/other/PrismsAnnotationSpec.scala`. To compile it, run `sbt test:compile`.

Comment: Any chance you're running into the same issue we see in circe [here](https://github.com/travisbrown/circe/issues/251)?

Comment: Are you trying to use macro annotation in the same compilation run that defines it?

Comment: @MilesSabin No, the annotation is defined in src/main of one subproject, and it's used src/test of a different subproject, so they're definitely different compilation runs.

Comment: Workaround for "annotation could not be expanded" https://stackoverflow.com/a/20466423/5249621