# Adding extra trait to object using scala macro annotation

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros, scala-macro-paradise

I'm on Scala 2.10.3 using Macro Paradise. I have a macro annotation where I'm trying to add a trait to on object, e.g:

```
@MyAnnotation
object Foo extends Bar {}
```

After expansion I want something like:

```
object Foo extends Bar with Baz {}
```

Where `Baz` is a trait accessible in the compilation scope. Using macro paradise I can cleanly destructure my target tree:

```
q"object $obj extends ..$bases { ..$body }" = tree
```

where bases holds the existing extensions in the form List of Ident(newTypeName("Bar"))

I could just add an extra `Baz` entry to bases and reconstruct the tree, the problem is the target might "already" contain `Baz`. In this case I don't want to add it. The term names given to me are shortened. Is there a way of converting them to actual type references inside the macro?

I've tried the following in the macro: `c.typeCheck(Ident(newTypeName("Baz")))` but I get the following error:

```
scala.reflect.macros.TypeCheckException: trait some.Baz is not a value
```

I've looked through context to see if theres any other obvious methods to use, but none jumps out.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In Scala 2.10, c.typeCheck always treats its argument as a term, and you need to go the extra mile to typecheck a tree representing a type.

This answer explains a workaround to typecheck something as a type and outlines a limitation specific to macro annotations: [Can't access Parent's Members while dealing with Macro Annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379436/cant-access-parents-members-while-dealing-with-macro-annotations).

Comment: So in my example object Foo is inside another object, lets say call object Outer. When I try c.typeCheck(Block(annottees.head.tree.duplicate)) I get a illegal cyclic reference error. Its pulling in the containing object and thus itself again.

Comment: Is there a way of using the current Context to resolve Baz to some.Baz ? Judging by the error returned it must be doing that internally.

Comment: Could you post your code example at github? I'll try to help.