# How do I resolve a short type name to a full type name in a Macro

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, scala-macros

Inside a macro is there a way of using the current Context to fully expand a type name? Eg something like:

```
context.resolveShortTypeNameToFullTypeName("Foo") = "com.acme.Foo"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your macro might expand in a tree that includes an arbitrary `import prefix.Foo`, so you're asking if you can query that enclosing tree: If I emit a name `Foo`, how would you typecheck it?

`symbol.fullName` is your answer.

```
val t = c.typeCheck(q"??? : Foo").tpe.typeSymbol.fullName
```

or use `c.typecheck` in 2.11.

or, if you can't find the scaladoc...

```
val k = c.asInstanceOf[scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Context]
locally {
  import k.universe._
  val n = k.callsiteTyper.typed(q"??? : Foo").tpe.typeSymbol.fullName
  println(n)
}
```

Where is <strike>Travis Brown</strike> Eugene Burmakro [sic] when you need him?

Comment: Yes, indeed it is possible to typecheck trees in macro expansions. There's even a special method for that in the public API called c.typeCheck, so there's no need to cast. In Scala 2.10, typeCheck can only work with terms and requires a small workaround to typecheck a type: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680630/adding-extra-trait-to-object-using-scala-macro-annotation/21682269. In Scala 2.11, typechecking will have a dedicated mode for types.

Comment: @EugeneBurmako Thanks! I tried c.typecheck first and must have done something wrong.

Comment: Sorry—have a one-answer-max rule for my lunch breaks, and I'd [already spent mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21684752/334519) for today.

Comment: @som-snytt. We've slightly changed the name in 2.11 - now it's c.typecheck, not c.typeCheck like in Scala 2.10.