# Can I get the package/owner from a ClassDef in an impl of a Scala macro annotation?

Tags: scala, scala-macros

Given (Scala 2.10.3),

```
package models
@MyAnnotation
case class MyClass()
```

How do I get the package name in the impl of the macro?

I've tried:

1) A `typeCheck` like was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21683971/how-do-i-resolve-a-short-type-name-to-a-full-type-name-in-a-macro?lq=1), but that results in a stack overflow (although I can see it spitting out the correct full name).

```
val result = {
  annottees.map(_.tree).toList match {

    case classDef @ q"$mods class $name[..$tparams](..$first)(...$rest) extends ..$parents { $self => ..$body }" :: Nil => {

    val full = c.typeCheck(q"??? : $name").tpe.typeSymbol.fullName
...
```

2)  Collecting the `ClassDef` and calling `.symbol` reveals that it has none.

*I'd like to avoid:*

3) Passing in the value as an argument to the annotation.

4) Annotating the package and storing the name for use when expanding the class.

5) Parsing the context's `.enclosingPosition` with the hopes that package and directory structure corresponds.

Did I botch the `typeCheck`? Should I settle for #3 or #4? Any suggestions how to accomplish my goal?

Thanks very much for any input,

-Julian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would typecheck a dummy definition, e.g. `c.typeCheck(q"class Dummy${newTypeName(c.fresh())}")` and then look into its symbol. Walking the `Symbol.owner` chain of that symbol would reveal the enclosing package.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that would be great, but the compiler complained: `[error] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments`. So I added `Modifiers()` like so: `c.typeCheck(q"class Dummy ${newTypeName(c.fresh()); Modifiers() }") `, but that resulted in a typer error: `[error]   last tree to typer: type Dummy
[error]               symbol: <none> (flags: )
[error]    symbol definition: <none>
[error]        symbol owners: 
[error]       context owners: `  -- Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, here's on the right track:      `val freshName = c.fresh(newTypeName("Probe$"))
     val probe = c.typeCheck(q""" {class $freshName; ()} """)
     val owner = probe match {
       case Block(List(t), r) => t.symbol.owner
     }` Much obliged.