# Obtaining a WeakTypeTag for a given type in a Scala macro annotation

Tags: scala, reflection, macros, scala-macros

I'm writing a Scala macro annotation `@model` used to annotate my case classes and which automatically adds some metadata to the companion object of the annotated class, based on the fields of the annotated case class.

I would like to obtain more information about the type of the case class's parameters, especially, check if they implement a certain trait. I thought obtaining a `WeakTypeTag` for them was the way to go, but I can't seem to get one the way they are obtained in def macros.

Concretely: I want to be able to tell in this case, from the macro implementation of `@model`, that the `address` field of the `User` class has a type which extends `ModelObject`, and that `date` doesn't. Can I do that?

```
trait ModelObject
@model case case Address(street: String, city: String) extends ModelObject
@model case class User(name: String, since: Date, address: Address) extends ModelObject
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trees that go into macro annotation arguments are purposefully untyped. However running `c.typeCheck(q"(??? : <tree that represents the parent>)").tpe` will provide the missing information. Don't forget to `duplicate` that tree before typechecking, because `c.typeCheck` mutates the tree in place, which might be undesireable.

There are limitations to what `c.typeCheck` can do. For some examples of that, see [Can't access Parent's Members while dealing with Macro Annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379436/cant-access-parents-members-while-dealing-with-macro-annotations).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Eugene. I'm trying `val tpe = c.typeCheck(q"(???: $typeTree)").tpe`, where `typeTree` is the `tpt` member of the `ValDef` I'm inspecting, but I get the error “c.universe.Name expected but c.universe.Tree found”. What am I missing?

Comment: Great, this works, thanks a lot! Is it such a special use case that it wouldn't warrant adding something like `c.typeOf(tree)` that would do this?

Comment: Well, I typically try to avoid adding stuff to public API, especially if it can be easily expressed with existing facilities. The benefit of trading `c.typeCheck(tree).tpe` for `c.typeOf(tree)` doesn't seem to overweigh the downside of inflating the API.

Comment: What we did improve, though, is the API to typecheck types. In 2.11, you can do `c.typecheck(tree, c.TYPEmode)` instead of the q"(??? : ...)" thing mentioned in the answer. What do you think?

Comment: You’re right—I’m probably just too unfamiliar with macros and the related APIs yet.