# How to check if some type confirms to generic type bounds in Scala macros?

Tags: scala, generics, macros, scala-macros, type-bounds

I have the following method in some class:

```
def writeGeneric[G <: GenericTrait](value: G)
```

I'm processing that method using Scala macros. Extracted type params for this method `m.typeParams` printed as `type G <: GenericTrait`.
Where the `m` is `MethodSymbol`.

How do I test if some other type confirms to this types bounds?
For example this doesn't work:

```
typeOf[OtherType] <:< m.typeParams.head.typeSignature
```

Comment: Have you looked at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965857/obtaining-a-weaktypetag-for-a-given-type-in-a-scala-macro-annotation

Comment: I've seen that question. If I understood `typeCheck` allows to retrieve type information from tree. In my case I already have a type information. I need a function that validates that one type could be used as a generic type argument. That it  corresponds to that type argument constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found solution with manual bounds check:

```
val typeParamSymbol = m.typeParams.head
val other = typeOf[OtherType]

val typeMatched = typeParamSymbol.typeSignature match {
    case TypeBounds(lo,hi) ⇒
        lo <:< other && other <:< hi
    case other: Type ⇒
        left <:< other
}
```

Still hoping for a better solution.